# C++ - gcc-specific warnings

Tags: c++, gcc, warnings

Got the following warning output when using *GCC 4.5.0 & MinGW.*

```
Warning: .drectve `-aligncomm:___CTOR_LIST__,2 ' unrecognized
Warning: .drectve `-aligncomm:___DTOR_LIST__,2' unrecognized
```

What does it mean? I guess it's version-specific, because *GCC 4.3.4 under cygwin* didn't give that warning on the same project.

If anyone had the following output (just curious that's that about), please advise me what to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmmm, Google does wonders:
[GCC failure](http://old.nabble.com/linking-objc-program-with-gcc-4.5.0-fails-td28472348.html)
[Broken on Cygwin](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2007-03/msg00948.html)

The advice, try reloading and rebuilding GCC or load a prior version.